# Speed up my lexing algorithm

Tags: ruby, lexical-analysis

I'm splitting a potentially large string (let's say 20MB, though this is entirely arbitrary) into tokens defined by a list of regular expressions.

My current algorithm takes the following approach:

1. All regexes are optimized to have the zero-width assertion `^` at the start of them
2. For each regex in the list, I attempt to `#slice!` the input string
3. If we `#slice!` anything, we got a match AND the input string has been advanced ready to find the next token (since `#slice!` modifies the string)

Unfortunately this is slow, which is due to the repeated `#slice!` on the long string... it seems like modifying large strings in ruby isn't fast.

So I wonder if there's a way to match a my regexes against the new substring (i.e. the remainder of the string) without modifying it?

Current algorithm in (tested, runnable) pseudo-code:

```
  rules = {
    :foo => /^foo/,
    :bar => /^bar/,
    :int => /^[0-9]+/
  }

  input = "1foofoo23456bar1foo"
  # or if you want your computer to cry
  # input = "1foofoo23456bar1foo" * 1_000_000

  tokens = []

  until input.length == 0
    matched = rules.detect do |(name, re)|
      if match = input.slice!(re)
        tokens << { :rule => name, :value => match }
      end
    end

    raise "Uncomsumed input: #{input}" unless matched
  end

  pp tokens
  # =>
  [{:rule=>:int, :value=>"1"},
   {:rule=>:foo, :value=>"foo"},
   {:rule=>:foo, :value=>"foo"},
   {:rule=>:int, :value=>"23456"},
   {:rule=>:bar, :value=>"bar"},
   {:rule=>:int, :value=>"1"},
   {:rule=>:foo, :value=>"foo"}]
```

Note that while quite simply matching the regexes against the string an equivalent number of times is not fast by any means, it is not so slow that you'd have time to cook a pizza while you wait (a few seconds, vs many many minutes).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`String#match()`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-match) method has a two-parameter version, which will match a regular expression starting at a specific character position in the string. You just need to get [one-past-the-last-matching-character from the *previous* match](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/MatchData.html) as the starting position for the new match.

In untested, not-run pseudo-code:

```
input = "foo"
input_pos = 0
input_end = input.length

until input_pos == input_end do
  matched = rules.detect do |(name, re)|
    if match = input.match(re, input_pos)
        tokens << { :rule => name, :value => match }
        input_pos = match.post_match
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I was hopeful that this would be the solution, but the regular expressions don't match with that `^` at the start if `pos` is passed to `#match` and without that constraint, the regex would waste a lot of time scanning the entire 20MB string for each iteration of the loop.  I can't see an easy way to have the regex behave like it's looking at the start of a string.  I guess I could prefix some sort of marker, but then we're back into the territory of repeatedly creating/modifying strings :)

Comment: Maybe if you replace the `^` with `\G` to match from the end of the previous match, it'll work? ... though the first matches might require more work. I hope [pguardiario's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8200195/speed-up-my-lexing-algorithm/8200774#8200774) works out. :)

Comment: Holy crap. This is at least 30 times faster than my code, possibly more (I wasn't benchmarking with sub-second accuracy due to the huge times we were looking at). Thanks!  I never knew about `\G`.  I'm now matching 70,000 tokens in under a second (instead of 30 seconds).

Comment: That's just awesome! Superb. :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm oversimplifying but String#scan will most likely outperform anything else:

```
tokens = input.scan(/foo|bar|\d+/).map{|m| {:value => m, :rule => rules.find{|name,re| m =~ re}[0]}}
```

or more generally:

```
rules = {
    :foo => /foo/,
    :bar => /bar/,
    :int => /[0-9]+/
}
tokens = input.scan(Regexp.union(rules.values)).map{|m| {:value => m, :rule => rules.find{|name,re| m =~ re}[0]}}
```

Comment: Yeah, over-simplifying ;)  I need to be able to report at what point matching fails, but also, I have some rules that do some state switching (for example, to lex inside of interpolated strings).

Comment: In that case please add an example of that rule to the question.